# Concat statement in mysql with PHP causes mysqli_query to return false

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have the following query:

```
$sqlquery="SELECT CONCAT_WS(".",php_version_major, php_version_minor, php_version_build) AS phpversion, COUNT(id) AS COUNT, YEAR(createdate) AS YEAR, MONTH(createdate) AS MONTH FROM logs_checklist_interface GROUP BY phpversion, YEAR(createdate), MONTH(createdate) ORDER BY createdate ASC";

$rsData=mysqli_query($dblink,$sqlquery);
```

$rsData returns FALSE with this query.   The cause seems to be the concat_ws statement.  If I remove that it works fine.  I've tried the other CONCAT function and it's the same result.

What is wrong with such a simple statement that causes mysqli_query() to get upset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
$myString = "abc" . "xyz";
```

You get a string `abcxyz`, not `abc"."xyz`

I suppose that you think that `"` means something different to PHP in the cases where you intended it to be used as a string delimiter in an SQL expression.

```
$sqlquery="SELECT CONCAT_WS(".",php_version_major,
          ^ php quote       ^ ^ sql string delimiters?
```

But unfortunately, that's not true. PHP sees both instances of `"` as PHP quotes. Therefore this is two PHP strings, using the PHP string concatenation operator `.`.

So the resulting SQL query is:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(,php_version_major, ...
```

This has a comma directly after the parenthesis, so it's nonsense syntax.

Comment: A habit I follow is to use double-quotes for PHP string delimiters, and single-quotes inside that string for SQL string delimiters. That way it's not ambiguous, and it's better to use single-quotes in SQL syntax anyway.